# How to deploy changes to java file into AEM?

Tags: workflow, aem, adobe-brackets

I'm working with AEM for the first time. I am using Adobe Brackets for editing one of the ZIP files I was given that included `jcr_root` and `META-INF`. This ZIP file has no `pom.xml`. Everything so far is fine with the zip file....I can make changes to JSP and JS etc. and they take effect right away.

However, I would like to change one of the java files. The change to JAVA files doesn't seem to be taking effect. I've restarted CQ instance but that doesn't seem to be working. And there is no POM.xml in the zip file.

There is a `.bnd` file with these contents. Not sure if this helps..

```
Export-Package: *
Import-Package: *
#Private-Package: com.acme.demo.workflow.impl
# Include-Resource: 
Bundle-Name: com.acme.demo.workflow
Bundle-Description: 
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.acme.demo.workflow
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Bundle-Activator: com.acme.demo.workflow.Activator
```

**Question**

Can compiled class files be sent to AEM via brackets? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use Maven to build your AEM Project. It's very well supported and documented and the de-facto standard for AEM deployment.
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developmenttools/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html

Comment: I asked another question, hope that makes more sense http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699726/how-to-work-with-a-bundle-in-eclipse-when-it-was-downloaded-from-aem

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use Eclipse IDE, follow next steps:
Use maven command on bundle's pom.xml file

1. rightclick on pom.xml file of bundle.
2. Run as.
3. Run configurations.
4. In Base derictory field browse package of your bundle.
5. In Goals field

Put this string

```
install org.apache.sling:maven-sling-plugin:install -Dsling.url=http://SERVERNAME/system/console/install -Dsling.user=admin -Dsling.password=admin
```

Press Run button and yours bundle will be installed to CRX

You can check if bundle installed using link

```
http://SERVENAME/system/console/bundles
```

Comment: I asked another question, hope that makes more sense http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699726/how-to-work-with-a-bundle-in-eclipse-when-it-was-downloaded-from-aem

Answer (score 0):

The surest way is through maven only. At the parent pom's directory level hit - 
[image: mvn clean install -DskipTests -PautoInstallPackagePublish]

Definitely fast and reliable. Although it is not advisable to disable tests everytime.