# How to work with a bundle in eclipse when it was downloaded from AEM

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, aem, sling

I downloaded a zip from a running instance of AEM from package manager   - `http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/index.jsp`. The zip file, when extracted contains, `jcr_root` and `META-INF`.

I would like to build some functionality on top of this zip file. So I'm wondering if there is a way to work with this file in eclipse? However, there are no `pom.xml` files in this zip folder. So I can't just import it in Eclipse. I have AEM developer tools downloaded for Eclipse.

Is there a guide available that explains how to do this? The zip file contains some Java files and I would like to make changes to those Java files and re-package, re-deploy, so that I can test my changes.

I tried using Adobe Brackets (with AEM extension) but it only works well for JS or JSP changes...not for JAVA files.

**Update**

After @Gabriel's comment, this is my understanding of how I need to move around 
**from** the package I downloaded **to** the new project created via eclipse.

[image]

***After doing the above***

Here is what the new eclipse project looks like after I've copy/pasted everything

[image]

***Contents of filter.xml from downloaded package***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/etc/designs/delta"/>
    <filter root="/apps/delta"/>
    <filter root="/content/delta"/>
    <filter root="/content/dam/delta"/>
    <filter root="/content/usergenerated/content/delta"/>
    <filter root="/apps/foundation/components/parsys"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

Based on above I changed two filter.xml in following locations

`/myproj.ui.apps/src/main/content/META-INF/vault/filter.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/myproject">
        <exclude pattern="/apps/myproject/install" />
    </filter>
    <filter root="/apps/foundation/components/parsys" />
    <filter root="/etc/designs/delta"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

`/myproj.ui.content/src/main/content/META-INF/vault/filter.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/content/myproject"/>
    <filter root="/content/dam/myproject"/>
    <filter root="/content/usergenerated/content/delta"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

Doing clean/publish seemed to have no effect as I didn't see anything in CRX or `localhost:4502/siteadmin` after doing clean/publish. So I tried to install manually.

For that I did `Run as -> Maven Install` on myproj (which builds the following zip files)

```
~/Documents/workspace/myproj $ tree | grep "zip"
│       ├── myproj.ui.apps-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
        ├── myproj.ui.content-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

When I upload & install these two files to CRX I see the following:

[image]
[image]

However, this also seems to not be having any effect because I don't see anything in `localhost:4502/siteadmin` and when I visit `localhost:4502/content/myproj` I get an error

``

BTW this is what I see under `localhost:4502/siteadmin`

[image]

**Update 2**

After going through everything again I was able to create the eclipse project and was successful in clean/publishing. However, changes to JAVA files aren't being reflected when I do clean/publish.

@Gabriel mentioned that

> PROJECT.core for Java bundles (these will become interesting as soon
>   as you want to add Java code)

I have java files already that are in `PROJECT.ui.apps` as shown in the image below

[image]

If I make a change to this JAVA file and clean/publish, my changes aren't being reflected in AEM. Is there something else that needs to be done to be able to change and publish JAVA code? or How can I make changes to JAVA files and test that on AEM?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think that your `filter.xml` in `myproj.ui.apps` should filter `/apps/delta` instead of `/apps/myproject`. Similar error for `myproj.ui.content` where you should filter for `/content/delta` and `/content/dam/delta` instead of `*/myproject`.

Comment: The Java bundles that are in your `/apps` structure have to be moved into `PROJECT.core`, or their synchronization won't work. The reason is that content projects (like `PROJECT.ui.apps` and `PROJECT.ui.content`) are synched into JCR, while bundle projects (like `PROJECT.core`) must be synched into OSGi. But then you also have to edit accordingly the POM.xml of `PROJECT.core`, which is not trivial.

Comment: @GabrielWalt Thanks, I will try to move the JAVA files from `/apps` to `PROJECT.core`. I'll read up on how to edit the POM.xml according to that. Any hints regarding it?

Comment: You can have a look at following page: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developmenttools/how-to-build-aem-projects-using-apache-maven.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the New Project feature to create the right structure for you:

- In Eclipse do **File** > **New** > **Project...**
- Choose **AEM** > **AEM Sample Multi-Module Project** > **Next**
- Pick the latest Archetype version
- Enter the **Name**, **Group Id**, and **Artefact Id** > **Next**
- Either **Add to existing server** if there's already one and pick the **Location**, else choose **Setup new server** and fill all fields > **Finish**
- Wait for Eclipse to finish setting up everything

You now have following projects created for you, which will allow healthy separation of concerns:

- `PROJECT.ui.apps` for `/apps` and `/etc` content
- `PROJECT.ui.content` for `/content` that is authored
- `PROJECT.core` for Java bundles (these will become interesting as soon as you want to add Java code)
- `PROJECT.it.launcher` and `PROJECT.it.tests` for integration tests (you can ignore these as long as you don't run any integration tests)

First, replace the content of your `PROJECT.ui.apps` project with the `apps` and `etc` folders of your package:

- In the **Project Explorer** panel, unfold `PROJECT.ui.apps` > `src` > `main` > `content` > `jcr_root` > `apps`
- Right-click on the `apps` folder and choose **Show In** > **System Exporer**
- Delete the `apps` and `etc` folders that you should now be seeing and place here the `apps` and `etc` folders of your of your content package
- In Eclipse, right-click on the `PROJECT.ui.apps` project and choose **Refresh**

Then do the same for the `PROJECT.ui.content` and replace it's `content` folder with the one of your package:

- In the **Project Explorer** panel, unfold `PROJECT.ui.content` > `src` > `main` > `content` > `jcr_root` > `content`
- Right-click on the deeper `content` folder and choose **Show In** > **System Exporer**
- Delete the `content` folder that you should now be seeing and place here the `content` folder of your of your content package
- In Eclipse, right-click on the `PROJECT.ui.content` project and choose **Refresh**

Now you have to update the `filter.xml` files of these two projects to correspond to the content of your content package.
For that, open the `META-INF/vault/filter.xml` file of your content package in a separate text/code editor.

This is an example of how your `filter.xml` file can look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/foo"/>
    <filter root="/apps/foundation/components/bar"/>
    <filter root="/etc/designs/foo"/>
    <filter root="/content/foo"/>
    <filter root="/content/dam/foo"/>
    <filter root="/content/usergenerated/content/foo"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

As for the content of your package that got split into two projects, you'll also have to split these filter rules into two and update accordingly the `filter.xml` files of the two projects.

- In Eclipse, open `PROJECT.ui.apps/src/main/content/META-INF/filter.xml`
- Replace the content of the `<workspaceFilter>` element with the rules of your package that start with `/apps` and `/etc`
- Then open `PROJECT.ui.content/src/main/content/META-INF/filter.xml`
- Replace the rules with the ones of your package that start with `/content`

Based on the above example, this is how the `filter.xml` of `PROJECT.ui.apps` would look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/foo"/>
    <filter root="/apps/foundation/components/bar"/>
    <filter root="/etc/designs/foo"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

And the one of `PROJECT.ui.content`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/content/foo"/>
    <filter root="/content/dam/foo"/>
    <filter root="/content/usergenerated/content/foo"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

Make sure to **Save** all your changes. You should now be done, and can synchronize that new content to your AEM instance.

- In the **Servers** panel, make sure that your connection is `[Started]`, and if not start it
- Click on the **Clean and Publish** icon (the last one)

Once done, you should have your package running on your instance, and on save, any change automatically get synchronized to the instance.

If you wish to re-build a package out of your project:

- Right-click on the `PROJECT.ui.apps` or `PROJECT.ui.content` and choose **Run As** > **Maven Install**
- You now have a `target` folder that has been created with your package inside (called for e.g. `PROJECT.ui.apps-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip`).

Comment: I've been able to create the project now. However, the project has JAVA files and when I change them and then do clean/publish, the changes don't seem to be taking effect on AEM. Changing JS, JSP, CSS files seems to be taking effect with clean/publish. But not JAVA files.

Comment: One issue I observed was, when we create new project (windows, eclipse luna), finish filling all details. It moves eclipse to non-responding state for about 2-5 mins, and then project is created. Is this known behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to create new pom file for downloaded bundle.
[Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/first-osgi.html) you can see how to create bundle. Also after creating file, you will be able to use [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689454/how-to-deploy-changes-to-java-file-into-aem/29695133?noredirect=1#answer-29695133) to deploy bundle after any changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the aem-project-archetype:10 to generate your projects then there will be a few differences/corrections:

The filters files are correctly generated (but in defferent paths):

- ui.apps\src\main\content\META-INF\vault\filter.xml.
- ui.content\src\main\content\META-INF\vault\filter.xml.

so, you won't need to fix these files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/product-name">
        <exclude pattern="/apps/product-name/install" />
    </filter>
    <filter root="/apps/sling" />
    <filter root="/etc/designs/product-name"/>
</workspaceFilter>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/content/product-name"/>
    <filter root="/content/dam/product-name"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```