# Importing AEM projects into Eclipse

Tags: aem

I have searched around and couldn't find a direct answer in how to import an existing AEM project on my local into Eclipse. I am relativity new to AEM and would like to use the features Eclipse has. I have the AEM plug in downloaded and am able to create a new project, just not import.

I am not using maven, just packages and OSGI.

Advice?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use Maven?

Comment: It is the way we have the project built. If I could go back and do it I would but I cannot.

Comment: I've never worked on an AEM project that wasn't just built from a Maven archetype so I'm afraid I cannot help much. This question seems related, have you seen it? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29705407/1407656

Comment: Well how could I make the project into a maven project? In other words, I have about 80 jar files and we have been using CRXDE Lite.

Comment: Have you tried to solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170963/how-to-make-an-existing-directory-into-an-eclipse-project

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new AEM archetype project (provided by the AEM eclipse plugin). That project will be a maven project.
Since you are not using maven in your current project, you can manually move all of your java files into their respective location on the newly created AEM project. As for the java dependencies, you can lookup tutorials on how to use maven and add your java dependencies to it. or you can just add your dependencies directly on the project, but I recommend using maven.

Answer (score 0):

You have only package and OSGI bundle, so you can only modify the content (package) and cannot modify the bundle.

We cannot import a project from the osgi bundle to make the source code editable.

Answer (score 0):

For import AEM project to Eclipse, follow the procedure:

- Import AEM project as maven projects. Please check with image. [image]
- Then select your project and build.

Answer (score 0):

From where you are getting those packages and bundles?

When ever you build the project from the source(cmd : mvn clean install), packages/bundles will be generated under respective target folder based on pom.

So, you can only import project source on eclipse and not the generated target files.